# UserControl to avoid duplicating menu on every Page

Tags: c#, user-controls

My question is as follows: my app needs to show a "Hamburger" menu in the left side, while the content right of it changes depending on the context. My initial idea was to implement it with Frames inside different `Page`s. I learned that the `Frame` itself is a reference to `rootFrame` so there's really no need for nested `Frame`s to get navigation going.

However, to get the Hamburger menu on all `Page`s I would need to include them somehow. Is there a possibility to avoid duplicating the XAML code in every Page?

Looking into this I found `UserControl`. The docs are a bit hard to understand for me. Say I implemented a `UserControl` in XAML and named a `Button` in it via `x:Name="HamburgerButton". Then, in my`MainPage` I put something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <controls:MyControl />
</Grid>
```

The `Button` in the `UserControl` XAML has a `Click` event in the code behind. How do I extend / customize the implementation of it in the `MainPage` that uses it? I guess I don't understand the relationships between them. Also the `ContentPresenter` is over my head at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ContentPresenter. That's for when you create your own templates. Your MainView should contain your Menu buttons and a ContentControl. When a user clicks one of the buttons, you exchange the Content property of the ContentControl: For each menu item you can create an extra UserControl, one of which is always set to the ContentControl. For example, when the user clicks "Menu X" then you set the Content property of your ContentControl to UserControlX that contains all the context-related things. When the user clicks "Button Y" ... you get the idea.

You can do all this from the code-behind file of your main view. In the long run, you'll probably want to look into the MVVM pattern and bind your ContentPresenter to a property of your MainView's view model - and your buttons potentially to ICommands. But it will also work via the code-behind method.

Comment: Setting the `Content` to a `UserControl`: what's the difference of doing this with `Frame`s? Should the UserControl contain unique implementations (like with a Frame?) I thought the point of this type of Control is to reuse it.

Comment: A Frame can be used to display pages or other elements, including HTML. It implements some additional features, such as navigation history. If you do not need this, you can use a ContentControl instead of a Frame and UserControls to specify the "pages". In this case, the UserControls will have little re-use value, they're there to provide structure. In other cases, UCs can be used to form new re-usable composite controls from existing ones.